# how to pull a docker image onto an unsupported platform

Tags: windows, docker

I have a docker image that I am trying to pull for the express purpose of analysing and reverse engineering (not running). The docker image is built for windows, and when I try to pull it, I get an error that says no builds for linux/amd64. How do I circumvent this and pull the windows image anyway?

I have attempted to specify in the tags that I wanted the windows amd64 version, but It does not allow me to pull the image